# Problem when trying to go back to main menu from sub menu(s) Java

Tags: java

Running into a problem with going back to the main menu in my Banking app. I have created a class called menu that has the functionality for my app and driver that contains the main method to run the program. I give the exit condition with `boolean gobackmainMenu` (declared in class scope) but as soon as I enter 0 for the logout option as my choice the program exits entirely and doesn't go back to main menu. Here's my code snippets of the methods I'm using. `runMenu()` is called in Driver(main function).

```
public void runMenu() {
        printHeader();
        while(!exit) {
            printMenuMM();
            int choice= getInputMainMenu();
            loginRegister(choice);
            
        }
    }
```

Prints the menus to the console

```
private void printMenuMM() {
        
        System.out.println("\nPlease Make A Selection");
        System.out.println("1)Register");
        System.out.println("2)Login");
        System.out.println("0)Exit");
    }
    private void printMenuCusAccM() {
        System.out.println("\nPlease Make A Selection");
        System.out.println("1) Apply for an account");
        System.out.println("2) Deposit in account");
        System.out.println("3) Withdraw from an account");
        System.out.println("4) Transfer Funds");
        System.out.println("0) Logout");
    }
```

Used to login and register accounts

```
private void loginRegister(int choice) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
        AccountService accService = new AccountService();
        AuthenticationService aService= new AuthenticationService();
        String username;
        String password;
        String spassword;
        String role1;
        String email;
        Role role;
        String address;
        String fullname;
        boolean enumTypeExists;
        //double amount;
        IntUserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();
        IAccountDAO accDao = new AccountDAO();
        List<User> allUsers =userDao.findAll();
        List<Account>allAccounts=accDao.findAll();
        switch (choice) {
        case 0:
            exit=true;
            break;
        case 1: //Registers a user
            System.out.println("Enter full name: ");
            fullname= s.nextLine();
            
            
            System.out.println("Enter email: ");
            email= s.nextLine();
             
            
            System.out.println("Enter username: ");
            username= s.nextLine(); 
        
            boolean a=userService.usernameExists(username);
            if(a==true) {
                do {
                System.out.println("Username already exists enter in different username");
                System.out.println("Enter username: ");
                username=s.nextLine();
                a=userService.usernameExists(username);
                    
               
                }while(a);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter  password: ");
            password= s.nextLine();
        
            System.out.println("Enter  in account type: ");
            role1=s.nextLine();
            boolean j=aService.enumTypeExists(role1);
            
            if(j==false) {
                do {
                System.out.println("Not a valid account type");
                System.out.println("Enter in account type : ");
                role1=s.nextLine();
                
                j=aService.enumTypeExists(role1);
                    
               
                }while(!j);
            }
            role= Role.valueOf(role1);
            
        
            
            System.out.println("Enter  address: ");
            address= s.nextLine();
            temp    = userService.register(username, password, role, email,fullname, address);
            
            break;
        case 2:// login a user but do some input validation
            System.out.println("Enter login Username: ");
            username =s.nextLine();
            temp=userDao.findByUsername(username);
            
            
            boolean k= aService.usernameAuthentication(username);
            if(k==false) {
                do {
                System.out.println("Username does not exist enter in a valid username");
                System.out.println("Enter username: ");
                username=s.nextLine();
                k=aService.usernameAuthentication(username);
                
               
                }while(!k);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter login Password: ");
            password=s.nextLine();
            boolean m= aService.passwordAuthentication(username,password);
            if(m==false) {
                do {
                System.out.println("Password is not associated with user");
                System.out.println("Enter password: ");
                password=s.nextLine();
                m=aService.passwordAuthentication(username,password);
                
               
                }while(!m);
            }
            
            boolean c=userService.login(username, password);
            while(c) {
                
                if(temp.getRole().toString()=="Customer") {
                    
                    while(!gobackmainMenu) {
                    printMenuCusAccM();
                    int choice2= getInputCusAccM();
                    operonCusAcc(choice2);
                    }
                }
                if(temp.getRole().toString()=="Employee") {
                    printMenuEmpAccM();
                    while(!gobackmainMenu) {
                    int choice3= getInputEmpAccM();
                    operonEmpAcc(choice3);
                    
                    }
                }
                if(temp.getRole().toString()=="Admin") {
                    printMenuAdmAccM();
                    while(!gobackmainMenu) {
                    int choice4= getInputAdmAccM();
                    
                    }
                }
            }
            
            break;
        
            
        default:
            System.out.println("An unknown error has occured");
        }
            
    }
```

Used to switch between options

```
private int getInputMainMenu() {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice=-1;
        while(choice<0 || choice >2) {
            try {
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                choice=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again");
            }
        }
        return choice;
    }
    private int getInputCusAccM() {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice1=-1;
        while(choice1<0 || choice1 >4) {
            try {
                System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
                choice1=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try again");
            }
        }
        return choice1;
    }
```

**Expected Output**

```
***************************************************
            Welcome To The Banking                 
                    App                            
***************************************************

Please Make A Selection
1)Register
2)Login
0)Exit

Enter your choice: 2
Enter login Username: 
k9
Enter login Password: 
k9
Succesful login

Please Make A Selection
1) Apply for an account
2) Deposit in account
3) Withdraw from an account
4) Transfer Funds
0) Logout

Enter your choice: 0

Please Make A Selection
1)Register
2)Login
0)Exit

Enter your choice:
```

**Generated Output**

```
***************************************************
            Welcome To The Banking                 
                    App                            
***************************************************

Please Make A Selection
1)Register
2)Login
0)Exit

Enter your choice: 2
Enter login Username: 
k9
Enter login Password: 
k9
Succesful login

Please Make A Selection
1) Apply for an account
2) Deposit in account
3) Withdraw from an account
4) Transfer Funds
0) Logout

Enter your choice: 0

Please Make A Selection
1)Register
2)Login
0)Exit
```

Terminates program

Comment: The only handler I see for a `0` sets `exit = true`, hence you exit, with the caveats that (a) no idea of `runMenu` context, and (b) there's a lot of code to wade through to understand how you're trying to handle top-level input.

Answer (score 0):

Something happens inside operonCusAcc() or operonEmpAcc() method. As far as I can see Admin role doesn't have such a method.

If you need more help, please, share more code.

Something like this should happen:

```
private void operonCusAcc(int choice2) {
    switch (choice2) {
        case 0: runMenu();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is linked with loginRegister() method, you initialize Scanner each time you run method, but it seems that you don't close Scanner. 
It can be automatically closed with this construction

```
    try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        //Your code here
    }
```

Also I recommend to divide your big method into smaller ones to increase readability and structurize class.